# setStatic function in httpdispatcher

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am building a server in node.js but am unable to understant the function of setStatic in httpdispatcher in the this example that i got on the net..

```
            var http = require('http');
            var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
            //Lets define a port we want to listen to
            const PORT=8080; 

            //We need a function which handles requests and send response
            function handleRequest(request, response){
                //response.end('It Works(Refereshed)!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
                try{
                    console.log(request.url);
                    dispatcher.dispatch(request,response);

                }catch(err){console.log(err);}

            }

            //set all js/html/css as static during response
            dispatcher.setStatic('resources');

            dispatcher.onGet("/page1",function(req,res){
                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                res.end("Page one");
            });

            dispatcher.onPost("/page2",function(req,res){
                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                res.end("Get Post Data");
            });


            //Create a server
            var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

            //Lets start our server
            server.listen(PORT, function(){
                //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
                console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
            });
```

but when i run this file and type url like http://localhost:8080/resources/dwnl.png then i get the following in the terminal [TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings] and nothing shows on the browser but i have a dwnl.png under a resource folder

[image: this is the image]

Comment: try with http://localhost:8080/dwnl.png

Comment: no error displayed on the terminal but just a blank white screen on browser

Comment: can you attach your image here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add following line

```
dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);
```

before

```
dispatcher.setStatic('resources');
```

and try with http://localhost:8080/resources/dwnl.png

Comment: the directory containing the app.js file has a subdirectory called resources inside which the image is located

Comment: it must be visible in that case on browser. You can also give a try to express. It's good to serve requests.
Meanwhile I am checking with your code.

Comment: unfortunately it is now showing...and thanks for the help...plz let me know the complete directory structure once you have found the bug in mycode

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try it. And accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Node.js cannot find basic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612325/node-js-cannot-find-basic-functions) This answer explains that httpdispatcher must be instantiated before use using something like:

```
var httpdispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

var dispatcher = new httpdispatcher();
```

otherwise you will get runtime TypeErrors because dispatcher does not exist.