# Node.js cannot find basic functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just installed node.js(v7.1.0) and npm(3.10.9)with homebrew and I am trying to run a basic web server.

Edit* I now instantiate the dispatcher but still get the same error

---

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 8080;
var HttpDispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
var http           = require('http');
var dispatcher     = new HttpDispatcher();

dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);
dispatcher.setStatic('');

dispatcher.onGet("/page1", function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Page One');
});

var server = http.createServer().listen(port);


server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log('GOT');
    dispatcher.dispatch(req, res);  
});
```

---

when I run the command node server.js I get this error

```
dispatcher.setStaticDirname(__dirname);

TypeError: dispatcher.setStaticDirname is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/NodeJS/node_modules/server.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

I get the same error for the dispatcher.onGet call.

Comment: Did you add `httpdispatcher` on your package.json and run `npm install` ?

Comment: I ran the command 'npm install httpdispatcher' and still am getting the same error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not using `httpdispatcher` correctly. You must instantiate the dispatcher before using it.

```js
var HttpDispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
var dispatcher     = new HttpDispatcher();
```

Comment: That extra line did not seem to matter I am getting the same error

Comment: According to the documentation of this library, you must do it this way

Comment: Just for clarification, whenever you get a TypeError, know that you're trying to call a method (function) which is not a part of the Type you're using, according to httpdispatcher documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpdispatcher) you must have an instance of the httpdispatcher init before you can setStatic and onGet.

Comment: I've created a bin to demonstrate what I'm saying. http://www.webpackbin.com/4kw61MEbM

Comment: Thank you! The problem seems to be on my machine I ran what I had on a different one and it does work