# nodejs and setting up a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I have followed the exact same method as listed in the below link, but I can only can a blank page when I type "localhost://8080" in my broswer.
why is that. can anyone advice please?

[setStatic function in httpdispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392636/setstatic-function-in-httpdispatcher/49721505?noredirect=1#comment86456610_49721505)

Comment: Please share more code

Comment: type http://localhost:8080

Comment: Why do you want to use httpdispatcher ?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8080

Localhost is the address, not the protocol. "http" is the protocol. Roughly, it goes like this: "protocol://address:port".